# Proper tag for discussing tun interfaces

Tags: discussion, tags

I've noticed that many questions about `tun` network interfaces are tagged with the `[tunneling]` tag.  This doesn't seem appropriate since, as I understand things, such an interface doesn't provide tunneling per se.

Am I wrong on this or is there a better tag that should be used?

Comment: Why does it need a separate tag? Shouldn't [networking] + tag-for-the-OS be enough?